# How can i Hide a specific Tab component in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator, react-native-tabnavigator

In My code I want to Hide The Drawer Tab in Tabnavigator.
i will do many tries but its not working. please help me.

```
const Drawer=createDrawerNavigator({
Home:{screen:Home},

})
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
Drawer:{screen:Drawer},
Home: {screen: Home},
Categories:{screen:Cate},
ShortList:{screen:ShortList},
Account:{screen:Account},
},
}
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You can instead pu the tabs inside the drawer so the drawer would be hidden but available on all tabs

```
const Drawer=createDrawerNavigator({
Tabs:{screen:TabNavigator, navigationOptions: {drawerLabel: () => null}}
Home:{screen:Home}

})
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
Home: {screen: Home},
Categories:{screen:Cate},
ShortList:{screen:ShortList},
Account:{screen:Account},
},
}
);
```

Comment: well i am having more trouble with same code;
my scenario is: 
i have created a Header Component and put a drawer navigator. i am trying call it from Tab Navigator by clicking on a button. i am getting an error **undfeind is not an object, my it can find the function openDrawer()**
need some more Help.

Comment: Mmmm that may be a bad imprementation of the navigation prop

Comment: Is the function `this.props.navigation.openDrawer()` being called by Home/Cate/ShortList directly, or from a child component ?

Comment: Its 2021 and still can't ?